# Why is there no panel quantile regression with two-way fixed effects yet?

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, quantile-regression, two-way

I have been learning the quantile regression model recently, and my understanding is (possibly wrong) that quantile regression is essentially extracting the subsamples corresponding to a certain quantile, such as 0.9, for OLS regression.

1. Am I getting this right? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I searched the literature and found that there are a lot of articles on fixed effects panel quantile regression, but there are almost no articles on individual and time bidirectional fixed effects panel quantile regression. Blank as far as I know.
[image]

2. Why is there no panel quantile regression with two-way fixed effects yet?
3. Can bidirectional fixed-effect panel quantile regression be carried out according to the following process: first, de-mean the original panel data according to the traditional bidirectional fixed-effect model, and then cross-sectional quantile regression is carried out for the processed data?

Comment: Quantile regression, though tied to the Laplace distribution, is an attempt to be distribution-free.  Because of that it is not very efficient and is hard to generalize.  You might consider semiparametric models such as the proportional odds model which are more efficient and have been extended in a variety of ways including for longitudinal data, e.g., random effects models and Markov models as described [here](https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19).

Comment: Thank you so much, This is good reference material.

Comment: Thanks for the thanks.  But thanks on this site is expressed by clicking on the up arrow on the left of my comment.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I am struggling with your first comment. If trying to be distribution-free hurts quantile regression efficiency, why wouldn’t the same be true for a proportional odds model that also aims to be distribution-free?

Comment: Quantile regression reduces to ordinary sample quantiles when there is a single predictor and it is categorical.  That slices the sample size multiple ways, and sample quantiles are known to be inefficient (e.g., the sample median has efficiency $\frac{2}{\pi}$ compared to the mean when the data are from a Gaussian distribution).  Ordinal regression is efficient like the Wilcoxon test (efficiency $\frac{3}{\pi}$) which ranks over all $N$ observations.

Answer (score 2):

You should also keep in mind that quantile regression is different from creating or defining subsamples, to identify quantile coefficients. At least that is not what most estimators do.

What happens in the background is, that given certain conditions, one tries to identify specific quantiles of un unknown conditional distribution that vary across an unobserved component, which we usually identify  as the quantile rank.

Now, regarding two way fixed effects: As you say, there is no formal treatment of it that I can think of. However, there are two solutions that can be applied.

Canay 2011, which starts with an identification assumption similar to what you did:

$$Q_y(\tau|X) = \alpha_i + \gamma_j + x\beta(\tau)$$

which states that $\alpha_i$ and $\gamma_j$ are fixed across quantiles. In this case, you can first, "extract" the FE effect from Y, and then estimate the quantile regression on the rest:

$$Q_{y-\alpha_i -\gamma_j }(\tau|X) = x\beta(\tau)$$

This requires resampling to estimate SE

The other option is proposed by Machado Santos Silva 2019 (quantile via MM)

Here, you assume a specific functional form:

$$ y = \alpha_i + \gamma_j + x\beta + v_{it} * (a_i + g_j + x b)$$

and your quantile regression is given by:

$$q_y(\tau|X)= ( \alpha_i + q_v(\tau) * a_i) +(\gamma_j + q_v(\tau) * g_j) + X (\beta + q_v(\tau)*b)$$

$$q_y(\tau|X)=  \alpha_i(\tau) +\gamma_j (\tau) + X \beta(\tau)$$

In Stata, this can be estimated using the command `mmqreg` (SSC)

**References**

[Canay, Ivan A. 2011. “A Simple Approach to Quantile Regression for Panel Data.” The Econometrics Journal 14 (3): 368–86.](https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1368-423X.2011.00349.x)

[Machado, José A. F., and J. M. C. Santos Silva. 2019. “Quantiles via Moments.” Journal of Econometrics 213 (1): 145–73.](https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jeconom.2019.04.009)